# Resize and placement of elements

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

```
public class InputURL {

public InputURL() {
    input();
}

private static JFrame mainFrame = Launcher.returnFrame();
private static JPanel mainPanel;

private void input(){


//Defining a Panel on which everything will be set
mainPanel = new JPanel();
mainPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

//To put the GridBagLayout Constraints
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

//Set Panel Size
mainPanel.setSize(Constants.windowWidth,Constants.windowHeight);

//Setting the Input Box
JTextField inputURL = new JTextField();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
c.ipady = 50;
c.weightx = 0.0;
c.gridwidth = 3;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
mainPanel.add(inputURL, c);

//Adding the start button
JButton submitURL = new JButton(Constants.SUBMIT_URL_BUTTON);
submitURL.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    //The action performed by the start button
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Execute when button is pressed
        }
});      

//The placement of the button
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
c.ipady = 50;
c.weightx = 0.0;
c.gridwidth = 3;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 2;
mainPanel.add(submitURL, c);


//Adding the components on Panel to Frame
mainFrame.add(mainPanel);

}
}
```

The ouput and expected output can be viewed here. Need help regarding the Output. E.G.:

[image]

I've tried using GridBagConstraints and for some reason I cannot play much with the UI.

Comment: For starters, `JTextField inputURL = new JTextField();` should be more like `JTextField inputURL = new JTextField(8);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot will come down to you final needs, for example, this just makes use of some of the basic properties of `GridBagConstraints`

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout();
    }

    public TestLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField inputURL;
        private JButton submitURL ;

        public TestPane() {
            inputURL = new JTextField(20);
            submitURL = new JButton("Submit the URL");
            submitURL.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
            add(new JLabel("Header"), gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 10, 20, 10);
            add(inputURL, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            gbc.weighty = 1.0;
            add(submitURL, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

A more complex solution might make use of compound layouts, using a mixture of `BorderLayout`, `GridLayout` and `GridBagLayout`

For example...

[image: Layout]

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private JTextField inputURL;
    private JButton submitURL ;

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel header = new JLabel("Header");
        header.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        header.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        inputURL = new JTextField(20);
        submitURL = new JButton("Submit the URL");
        submitURL.setMargin(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));

        JPanel field = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        field.add(inputURL);

        content.add(field);

        JPanel actions = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        actions.add(submitURL);

        content.add(actions);

        add(content);
    }

}
```

While it might sound stupid, spend more time focusing on the actual workflow of the user, this will lead you to the best layout decisions, rather then focus on the physical layout itself

Comment: The solution worked, thanks. Is there a specific method I should follow to adapt to the users workflow? Also, I have a had time understanding the selection of Layout. Can you please suggest something? I select layout which comes up to my mind first. @MadProgrammer

Comment: When designing a UI, look at the order of the fields, think about the relationship and groupings of the fields.  Most uses use a mouse, so you might want to consider having actions (buttons) close to the related fields so it's easier to navigate.  Default navigation of fields via the keyboard is generally defined by the layout manager and the order in which fields are laid out, so that's another consideration. Use white space to help de-clutter the screen, but also to demonstrate a disconnection between fields operations.

Comment: Which layout you choose comes down to needs. It's rare to find a single layout manager that will work for every thing (MigLayout and GridBagLayout are very flexible), but I tend to use a mixture of layouts to generate complex UIs based on what I want to achieve